Add translate="no" attribute in the elements generated from code listings
I'm using make4ht to convert .tex files to HTML, and I added google translate API to the generated website, but some elements shouldn't be translated and adding translate="no" attribute to the element can make it, something like:
<div>This will be translated</div>

<div translate="no">This will NOT be translated</div>

The elements that need to have this attribute are:
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}

and 

\lstinputlisting[]{}

My MWE of the tex file is bellow:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
This should be translated
\begin{lstlisting}
    This shouldn't be translated
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

And the .cfg file to add google translate:
\Preamble{xhtml,html5} 

\Configure{BODY}{
\HCode{<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
\Hnewline
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
\Hnewline
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>}}{}
  
\begin{document} 

\EndPreamble


Try this config file:
\Preamble{xhtml,html5} 

\Configure{BODY}{
\HCode{<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
\Hnewline
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
\Hnewline
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>}}{}

\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/before}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div translate="no">}}
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/after}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}

\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{lstinputlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gdef\start:LstLn{\HCode{<pre class="lstinputlisting" id="listing-\listingN" translate="no">}\gdef\start:LstLn{\HCode{\Hnewline}}}% ignore first newline, to prevent spurious line
    \bgroup\ttfamily%\special{t4ht@(}%
       \Configure{listings}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {\start:LstLn\HCode{<span class="label">}}%
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {%\special{t4ht@)}
    \egroup%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP  \HCode{</pre>}\par}%
\catcode`\:=12
  
\begin{document} 

\EndPreamble

For the environment, we use the \AddToHook command to prepend and append the <div> element. For \lstinputlisting, we need to change the original TeX4ht configuration, so the code is longer. The only change from the original is the translate="no" attribute.
This is the result:

